# « Inéluctable » et « inévitable » signifient-ils la même chose ?

Tags: sens, synonymes

Quelle est la différence entre « inéluctable » et « inévitable » ?

> Évolution inéluctable vers le désordre.
>
> Évolution inévitable vers le désordre.

Les propositions ci-dessus signifient la même chose ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oui! *Inéluctable* et *Inévitable* sont synonymes.

Si on veut finasser alors on peut considérer qu'*inéluctable* est resté plus proche de son sens latin qui portait l'idée de lutte, *éluctable* qualifiant ce qui peut être **surmonté**, évité en **luttant**.

Alors qu'il n'y a pas d'idée de lutte ou même d'effort dans l'évitement. Il suffit juste parfois de faire attention.

*Inéluctable* signifierait plus précisément : ***insurmontable***